# CSS hover doesn't work with multiple elements

Tags: html, css

What I am trying to do is hover over one element and change the display of another element within CSS. I asked a question on how to do this earlier and this worked, however, now I am adding multiple elements and it will not work. The code is below, am I missing something here?

CSS

```
.main-map {
    width: 700px;
    height: 558px;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 100px;
    background-image: url(map-london.png);
}

.contact-box {
    width: 250px;
    position: relative;
    float: right;
    height: 300px;
    margin-right: -160px;
    margin-top: -50px;
}



#contact1 {
    position: absolute;
    float: left;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 250px;
    height: 300px;
    display: none;
}

#hover1 {
    position: absolute;
    float: left;
    margin-top: 40px;
    margin-left: 230px;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background: aqua;
}

#hover1:hover + .contact-box > #contact1 {
    display: block;
}



#contact2 {
    position: absolute;
    float: left;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 250px;
    height: 300px;
    display: none;
}

#hover2 {
    position: absolute;
    float: left;
    margin-top: 130px;
    margin-left: 345px;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    background: red;
}

#hover2:hover + .contact-box > #contact2 {
    display: block;
}


#contact3 {
    position: absolute;
    float: left;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 250px;
    height: 300px;
    display: none;
}

#hover3 {
    position: absolute;
    float: left;
    margin-top: 190px;
    margin-left: 345px;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    background: blue;
}

#hover3:hover + .contact-box > #contact3 {
    display: block;
}
```

And the HTML

```
<div class="main-map">
          <div id="hover1"></div>
          <div id="hover2"></div>
          <div id="hover3"></div>


            <div class="contact-box">
                <div id="contact1">
                    This is a test.
                </div>


                <div id="contact2">
                    This is a test 2
                </div>

                <div id="contact3">
                    This is a test 3
                </div>
            </div>


        </div>
```

Comment: Take a look at **[this answer of mine..](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19885585/when-hover-a-image-the-rest-of-images-changes-the-filter/19885603#19885603)** this is possible without jQuery/JS so long as the elements are siblings, or at least descendants of the same parent.

Comment: Like this? http://jsfiddle.net/Josh_Powell/aL4Vz/1/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try replace [adjacent sibling selector `+`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors) with [general sibling selector `~`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_selectors).  Reason why it doesn't work when you added multiple elements was that because of adjascent sibling selector which will make it work only for your third item i.e `hover3` since `.contact-box` is immediately after that.

i.e

```
#hover1:hover ~ .contact-box > #contact1 {
    display: block;
}
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3ZHZr/)**

Also you can in fact generalize and combine some of those rules to:

HTML:

```
<div class="main-map">
    <div id="hover1" class="hover"></div>
    <div id="hover2" class="hover"></div>
    <div id="hover3" class="hover"></div>
    <div class="contact-box">
        <div class="contact">This is a test.</div>
        <div class="contact">This is a test 2</div>
        <div class="contact">This is a test 3</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.contact-box > .contact {
    position: absolute;
    float: left;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 250px;
    height: 300px;
    display: none;
}
#hover1 {
    margin-top: 40px;
    margin-left: 230px;
    background: aqua;
}
#hover3 {
    margin-top: 190px;
    margin-left: 345px;
    background: blue;
}
#hover2 {
    margin-top: 130px;
    margin-left: 345px;
    background: red;
}
.hover {
    position: absolute;
    float: left;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
}
.hover:nth-child(1):hover ~ .contact-box :nth-child(1), 
.hover:nth-child(2):hover ~ .contact-box :nth-child(2), 
.hover:nth-child(3):hover ~ .contact-box :nth-child(3) {
    display: block;
}
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/LWLFK/)**

Comment: 7 years later, you have saved me :) Was confused for a while as to why it won't work, and I used wrong selector. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

"+" is an "Adjacent" Sibling Selector. Adjacent means directly adjacent.

http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/adjacentsiblingselector

```
<h2>Heading</h2>
<p>The selector for this sibling is h2+p</p>
<p>The selector for this sibling is h2+p+p</p>
```